# Using variables and datasets to import tabular data into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to design a table in photoshop that will allow me to edit it's data with variables and datasets. I've attached an image to give you a basic idea of the variables that need to be in the table. This is a very simplified version, but you get the idea.
[image]

So far I've figured out how to create a .csv file that would work for one row of variables, but I don't know the best way to accomplish multiple rows. For a single row I used a spreadsheet, with the first row of each column being the name of the respective variable in PS, and the second row of each column being the value for that variable. I then exported the spreadsheet to a .csv and imported it to PS as a dataset.

Whats the best way for format the spreadsheet to accomplish tabular data? Ideally, I'd like to be able to enter the data in a way that makes sense in the spreadsheet, like so:
[image]

Obviously this doesn't work though, as photoshop reads each row as a possible value for the first row, rather than placing it in the corresponding row. So my question is, what is the best way to accomplish this?

This seems like it would be a pretty basic thing to accomplish, but after much searching I can't seem to find this question asked anywhere on google. I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If Photoshop is the only tool you're going to be in for a really tough time. This is much better suited for InDesign. Do you have InDesign and able to consider answers using it?

Comment: Its not very basic for photoshop.

Comment: Using data sets and variables does limit you to one row at a time unfortunately. Perhaps scriptung?

Comment: @Phlume Thanks for the answer. I've never done any kind of scripting with photoshop, so would you be able to give me some idea of what to google to find the information that would be relevant for this situation?

Comment: @Ryan (I'm reposting my response to you as I forgot to tag you the first time and was unable to edit.) 
 
I do have InDesign, but I'm trying to set this up for someone else to use, and they only have photoshop. That's why the goal is to make this as simple as possible to add new data.